# How can I send bitcoin to an address without a third party app?

Tags: client, privacy

Let's say I've generated a pub-priv key pair using ssh-keygen and loaded cash into it using an ATM. I've avoided using third parties thus far, so how can I continue this with sending bitcoin to a given public address?

Comment: `ssh-keygen`, as far as I know, does not support the secp256k1 curve that Bitcoin uses.

Comment: @PieterWuille sorry, openssl :)

Comment: What makes OpenSSL not a third-party app in a way that a Bitcoin wallet is?

Comment: @user144264 how do you know the ATM sent you anything at all?

Comment: You might want to use client library directly. Or make your own client.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin could be sent using software like Bitcoin Core, Electrum, Sparrow and a private key imported into it (in a particular format e.g. WIF which is not supported by OpenSSL).